# Is there a more specific reason to use "this" in Java other than style and readability?

Tags: java, class, this

I understand that "this" is a reference to the current object from within each method (it is also a reference to the implicit parameter). However, is there any reason to label the instance variables with "this" for any reason other than readability/style? I haven't found a decent explanation on when and why to use this from google or from the book I'm reading.

Comment: One case, which will often occur in constructors and setters, is when there is a local variable with the same name as an instance variable

Comment: This is something I have seen. I now realize I haven't ever passed arguments to my constructors with the same name as my instance variables. Is this commonly used as well within method parameters?

Comment: `this.outerClassName` can be used in lambdas and anonymous classes to reference the outer class instance. This can lead to memory leaks.